# How to load Python script and run custom code from the terminal in the single command?

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

Let's say I have a script called `device.py` which contains code like this:

```
class Simulator():
    def run():
        print('Running...')
```

From the shell script, I want to:

1. Open a new tab in the terminal.
2. Load this script to Python console.
3. Create `Simulator` instance and call its `run()` method. I *cannot* add this additional code to `device.py` script itself.

I imagine it should look like this:

```
SIMULATOR_DIR="$(pwd)/directory_to_script/"
gnome-terminal --working-directory=$SIMULATOR_DIR --tab -- bash -c "python -i device.py -c \"Simulator().run()\"" --title="Simulator (device)";
```

Anyway, while the script gets loaded to the interactive shell, it does not execute custom code provided with the `-c` flag.

How do I load Python script and execute custom Python code in the single command?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to accomplish with your planned approach?

Comment: @jjramsey I have a bunch of apps (not all of them are written in Python) and wanted to launch each of them in a separate tab. This is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have a class `Simulator` defined inside the `device.py` file, one thing you can do in order to execute methods on that class using an **inline** command is adding an import statement to your command.

You would then run:

```bash
python3 -c "from device import Simulator; Simulator().Run()"
```

Even though I don't know much about your specific problem, I would suggest you to reconsider your approach because, even if it works, it is generally not a good pattern to execute python scripts in that way.